# Scope of bean and reference bean

Tags: java, spring, scope, javabeans

In a spring application, 
Say Bean person is of scope prototype
and Bean address is of scope singleton

```
 Class person 
    {
    string name; 
    int age; 
    int rollno;
    Address address; 
    // Getters & Setters
    }

 Class Address 
{ 
int door_no; 
string street_name; 
// Getters & Setters 
}
```

It is obvious that a new instance will be created for **Person** each time when requested. 
now will a new instance be created for every request for **Address** or since it is referenced from person it will have the scope - prototype?

```
In sringBean.xml

    <bean id="studentBeanId" class="com.saro.corespring.autowire.Person"
        autowire="byName" scope="prototype">
        <property name="name" value="saro" />
        <property name="age" value="25" />
        <property name="roll_no" value="101" />
    </bean>

<bean id="addressBean" class="com.saro.corespring.autowire.Address" autowire="byType" scope="singleton">
        <property name="door_no" value="10" />
        <property name="street_name" value="Street Name" />
        </bean>
```

Comment: It will be Singleton Always.

Comment: To confirm on my understanding,  say i get the input from a jsp, although the values of Person bean changes, similarly the user input for address also may change right ? In that scenario ,will the address value will differ ? or the above value 10 & street name be carry forwarded through all instances of person object ?

Comment: Wherever you create these objects using Spring it will always behave same.

Comment: So the values "10" & "street name " will be the address for all the instances of persons . Please confirm.

Comment: Certainly Yes, it is.